# The new Google Groups interface—where is the pending members approve page?

Tags: google-groups

Under the old interface, I had a pending members tab, under the new one, I can’t find it anywhere. My group is by approval only—where do I go to approve pending members?

Answer (score 1):

If you have any pending members, the message (with link) will appear when you enter your group:

> There is one pending member to review

When you click this link, you will be redirected to site like this: `https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!pendingmember/<my-group-name>/apply`.

Alternatively, you can use this link: `https://groups.google.com/group/<my-group-name>/manage_members`. This is the *old* interface to manage members, and it has the pending users tab. Just type `pending` instead of `manage_members`.